# How to get a row with this same value in table

Tags: sql, oracle

My table `CASES` looks like this

```
| ID | Person_Number | Type |
```

And I need all rows in the `Cases` table with this same `Person_number` but rownumber must be higher than 1 (if only 1 row has a specific personnumber it is ignored) and row have to has a specific type

```
Select * 
from CASES
where type = 'TYPE1'
order by Person_NUMBER
```

but I have about 1 million different `person_number` but only few belong to more than 1 row.

Please help me

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I added sorry pl/sql

Comment: PL/SQL is again just a *language* - not a database system - that would be **Oracle** - added tag accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify your DBMS, so this is standard SQL using a window function:

```
select *
from (
  select c.*, count(*) over (partition by c.person_number) as number_count
  from cases c
  where c.type = 'TYPE1'
) t
where number_count > 1
order by person_number;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE cases AS
SELECT ROWNUM AS id, 
       TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (1, 1000000)) person_number, 
       'TYPE' || TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (1, 10)) TYPE
  FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 1000000;

CREATE INDEX CASES_I1 ON CASES(TYPE, PERSON_NUMBER);
```

By me the result is about 11000 records (1%) and this is a little bit faster than count(*) over (with the index of course ;) ) :

```
SELECT *
  FROM cases
 WHERE (TYPE, person_number) IN
    (SELECT TYPE, person_number
       FROM cases
      WHERE TYPE = 'TYPE1'
     GROUP BY TYPE, person_number
     HAVING COUNT (*) > 1)
```